# Node's spawn/exec not working when called from a scheduled Windows task

Tags: node.js, windows, scheduled-tasks

I'm facing a very odd issue where I have a Node script which invokes a process, it looks like this:

```js
  // wslPath declared here (it's a shell file)
  const proc = cp.spawn('ubuntu.exe', ['run', wslPath]);

  let stdout = '';
  proc.stdout.on('data', data => stdout += data.toString());

  let stderr = '';
  proc.stderr.on('data', data => stderr += data.toString());

  return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    proc.on('exit', async code => {
      await fs.remove(winPath);

      if (code) {
        reject({ code, stdout, stderr });
      }

      resolve({ stdout, stderr });
    });
  });
```

As you can see, the script invokes WSL. WSL is enabled on the computer. When I run this script manually, it works fine. When I log in to the computer the script is at using RDP from another computer and run it with the same credentials, it works fine as well. But when the script is invoked from a scheduled task which *also* runs with the same credentials, the `spawn` call returns:

```
(node:4684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: spawn UNKNOWN
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:394:11)
    at Object.spawn (child_process.js:540:9)
```

I verified the user is the same by logging `require('os').userInfo()` and `require('child_process').spawnSync('whoami', { encoding: 'utf8' })` and it returns the same in all three cases.

I assume it is because `ubuntu.exe` is not being found, but I don't know why that would be as the user is the same in all three cases.

What could be the reason for this and how can I debug this further?

Comment: You could try logging the contents of the ``PATH`` variable, as this contains all locations where windows will look for executables to run. Then you could see if these paths differ between your manual execution and your programmatic one.

Comment: A couple things to look into with your Windows task configuration.  Is the current directory set to what you want?  Is the right user and credentials set?  Does it work if you specify a full path to your executable?

Comment: @jfriend00 as stated, I did verify the credentials. The other stuff I also checked, mostly by using relative paths so it would break anyway but I double checked: work dir is given, the task invokes node which works (the script runs) and it invokes the script at the full path. I will try full path for Ubuntu in the script.

Comment: @LukasBach bingo! The PATH vaiable contents are (way) different. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: I think Windows Task Scheduler gives you the default system environment, not the environment for that user.  Not sure why, but I find it best to just assume you know nothing about the environment and use paths to everything or, in some cases, I launch my task through a .BAT file where I configure the things in the environment I need and then run my program in a known environment.  Perhaps they don't want subsequent changes in the user environment to be able to break or influence the task once it is defined.

Comment: This way the key, I had to spell out the path of `ubuntu.exe`. Now I'm getting *The system cannot execute the specified program* but that seems unrelated as it was finally able to at least _find_ it. Can you please answerize your comment so that I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Task Scheduler allows you to specify a user to run as (for privilege reasons), but does not give you the environment (PATH and other environment variables) that are configured for that user.

So, when running programs from the Windows Task Scheduler, it's important to not make any assumptions about what's in the environment (particularly the PATH).  If my program depends on certain things in the environment, I will sometimes change my Task to be a .BAT file that first sets up the environment as needed and then launch my program from there.

Among other things, the simplest way to not rely on the path is to specify the full path to the executable you are running rather than assuming it will be found in the path somewhere.  But, you also need to make sure that your executable can find any other resources it might need without any environment variables or you need to configure those environment variables for it before running.